# AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1344:Initialize: (err = PerformCommand(*outputNode, kAUInitialize, NULL, 0)): error -10851

Tags: ios, avaudioengine

I'm unable to run an iOS 13 app on a VM, getting this Xcode log:

```
MyApp[3272:16579] [ddagg]        AggregateDevice.mm:776   couldn't get default input device, ID = 0, err = 0!
MyApp[3272:16579] [ddagg]        AggregateDevice.mm:776   couldn't get default output device, ID = 0, err = 0!
MyApp[3272:16579]  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
MyApp[3272:16579] [aqme] AQMEIO.cpp:320:_FindIOUnit: error -66680 finding/initializing AQDefaultDevice
MyApp[3272:16377] [aurioc] AURemoteIO.cpp:1086:Initialize: failed: -10851 (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, inter> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, inter>)
MyApp[3272:16507] [aqme] AQMEIO.cpp:320:_FindIOUnit: error -66680 finding/initializing AQDefaultDevice
MyApp[3272:16377] [aurioc] AURemoteIO.cpp:1086:Initialize: failed: -10851 (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, inter>)
MyApp[3272:16377] [avae]            AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1344:Initialize: (err = PerformCommand(*outputNode, kAUInitialize, NULL, 0)): error -10851
```

Using Xcode 11.1, macOS 10.14.6

This error happens when I call start on my AVAudioEngine instance, after wiring up my nodes:

```swift
engine.attach(musicPlayer)
engine.attach(reverbNode)
engine.attach(mixerNode)
engine.connect(mixerNode, to: reverbNode, format: nil)
engine.connect(reverbNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)
try engine.start()
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused by the VM not having any audio inputs or outputs. An `AVAudioEngine`'s `start` function will throw an error if it can't find an audio input and audio output device.

Bitrise fixes it by suggesting the following:

> The solution is fortunately pretty simple, you can simply add a virtual audio output device if you need it. There are a few options to do this, probably the easiest is to install soundflower, which is a tool used for manipulating / piping audio between different tools, and it installs and uses a virtual (actually two) audio output to achieve the functionality.
>
> As the virtual audio drivers are installed as part of the soundflower installation, all you have to do is add a Script step to your workflow, any point before you’d use the audio output (can be the very first step of the workflow), with the following content:

```sh
set -ex
brew install Caskroom/cask/soundflower
brew install switchaudio-osx
SwitchAudioSource -s "Soundflower (2ch)" -t input
SwitchAudioSource -s "Soundflower (2ch)" -t output
```

Source: https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-output-device-on-mac-os-stacks/1119